# clustering in Servicemix using apache cellar

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

Aim is to create 2 instances of ServiceMix, starting both by changing the RMI host and port number in one of the nodes, installing apache cellar in both the ServiceMix nodes and deploy same bundle in both the nodes.

The bundle contains the routes which uses JM, ActiveMQ and CXF like endpoints. I did all these steps and the last step of bundle deployment in both works fine in node 1 and throws error in node 2 like below.

```
org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationException: null : Cannot start the broker
    at org.apache.activemq.osgi.ActiveMQServiceFactory.updated(ActiveMQServiceFactory.java:110)[92:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.10.0]
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.helper.ManagedServiceFactoryTracker.provideConfiguration(ManagedServiceFactoryTracker.java:88)[6:org.apache.felix.configadmin:1.8.0]
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.ConfigurationManager$ManagedServiceFactoryUpdate.provide(ConfigurationManager.java:1605)[6:org.apache.felix.configadmin:1.8.0]
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.ConfigurationManager$ManagedServiceFactoryUpdate.run(ConfigurationManager.java:1548)[6:org.apache.felix.configadmin:1.8.0]
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.UpdateThread.run(UpdateThread.java:103)[6:org.apache.felix.configadmin:1.8.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Transport Connector could not be registered in JMX: Failed to bind to server socket: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 due to: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at org.apache.activemq.util.IOExceptionSupport.create(IOExceptionSupport.java:27)[92:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.10.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.registerConnectorMBean(BrokerService.java:2069)[92:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.10.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startTransportConnector(BrokerService.java:2531)[92:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.10.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startAllConnectors(BrokerService.java:2448)[92:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.10.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.doStartBroker(BrokerService.java:693)[92:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.10.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startBroker(BrokerService.java:659)[92:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.10.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.start(BrokerService.java:595)[92:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.10.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.osgi.ActiveMQServiceFactory.updated(ActiveMQServiceFactory.java:104)[92:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.10.0]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to server socket: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 due to: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at org.apache.activemq.util.IOExceptionSupport.create(IOExceptionSupport.java:33)[92:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.10.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportServer.bind(TcpTransportServer.java:135)[92:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.10.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportFactory.doBind(TcpTransportFactory.java:56)[92:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.10.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactorySupport.bind(TransportFactorySupport.java:40)[92:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.10.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector.createTransportServer(TransportConnector.java:318)[92:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.10.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector.getServer(TransportConnector.java:144)[92:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.10.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector.asManagedConnector(TransportConnector.java:110)[92:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.10.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.registerConnectorMBean(BrokerService.java:2064)[92:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.10.0]
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_75]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:106)[:1.7.0_75]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)[:1.7.0_75]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:190)[:1.7.0_75]
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)[:1.7.0_75]
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)[:1.7.0_75]
    at javax.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(ServerSocketFactory.java:231)[:1.7.0_75]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportServer.bind(TcpTransportServer.java:132)[92:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.10.0]
```

I know this is because of the same ActiveMQ configuration (mainly port 61616) in both the nodes. But the idea of clustering is to use the same port, based on the load to one node, the other ServiceMix node should be called to service the request.

Correct me if im wrong. Am I going in the right path to achieve clustering?